# Rails: Polymorphic type relation or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism

I have three tables below.

Those are basically "Class Table Inheritance".

- Invoices
- CardInvoices
- BanktransferInvoices

```

```
Invoices
--------
- id
- total_amount
- invoiceable (either a CardInvoice *or* a BanktransferInvoice)

CardInvoices
--------
- id
- fee_amount
- gateway_error
- ...


BanktransferInvoices
--------
- id
- ...
```

```

Basically this is a has_one relation `Invoice => BankInvoice/CardInvoice`.

But I have to extract from other tables and insert data to those tables. (ETL things.)
So I do use raw SQL to insert data.

So I doubt the "Polymathic type model" above is clean or not, because

> First,
>   metadata has to be inserted to make it work. (Ex. Invoice_type)
>
> Second,
>   Constraints can't be applied.
>
> Third,
>   Direct join doesn't work.

So I'm thinking about changing the pointing direction.

`Invoice <= BankInvoice / CardInvocie`

With this, I can use the direct join, and check the constraint.

Now question is,

With the second way, how can I retrieve with BankInvoice / CardInvoice efficiently in Rails 4.2?
(I'm new to Rails. I think left outer join would be good. But the more Invoice types added, the more overhead there are.)

or can you suggest which implementation would be the better solution and why.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain your ETL things? @toshi

Comment: You might consider implementing the `BankInvoice` & `CardInvoice` models with Single Table Inheritance. Basically those models would use a single table and be distinguished from one another with a `type` field on that database table.  The Rails Guide to Associations (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) ends with a good section on STI. Once you've looked it over, you'll be able to decide if it makes sense for your exact set of circumstances